# Response.Redirect passing a value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

net c#.

I have a page A with this code

```
//ON PAGE A:        
string contentId = ContentIdFromUrl;
Response.Redirect("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId={0}"contentId);
```

and I need redirect the user to page B passing in the URL a variable in my case `ContentId`.

I receive a syntax error with my code.

Could you write a correct version?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the last line to:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId={0}",contentId));
```

as it won't compile as it is.

Update: Another way to do this is:

```
Response.Redirect("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId=" + contentId);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, now works, how do you call in C# this way to appending a variable to a string?

Comment: Updated to add alternative way using basic string concatenation instead.

Comment: You might want to remove {0} in your second option, no?

Comment: Spotted that a few seconds after submitting. Already removed it but thanks.

Comment: OK guys I really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 4):

```
string contentId = ContentIdFromUrl;
Response.Redirect("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(contentId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string contentId = ContentIdFromUrl;
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId={0}",contentId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/x/y/b.aspx?ContentId={0}",contentId));
```